# Facing difficulty in column data type in SQL Unpivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not very familiar to SQL query. Recently I have tried to build a query using `unpivot` functionality of SQL Server but I am facing an error that says:

> The type of column "U_ItemModality" conflicts with the type of other
>   columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Here is my query:

```
select 
    cast(unpvt.ItemCode collate database_default AS VARCHAR(30)) as ItemCode,
    cast(unpvt.attribute collate database_default AS VARCHAR(30)) as attribute,
    cast(unpvt.value collate database_default AS VARCHAR(30)) as value 
from [OITM]
unpivot (
    value for attribute in (U_Mfg_Part_Num, U_Part_Descriptor, U_ItemModality)
) unpvt
inner join [@AECTRANDATA] as WI 
    on unpvt.ItemCode = WI.U_ObjectKeyValue
inner join OITM AS IM 
    on WI.U_ObjectKeyValue = IM.ItemCode 
where 
    WI.U_ObjectType ='4'
```

In this query, if I remove `u_itemmodality` it will run. The other two columns have size of `100` character but this column have size of `30` character.

What to do to overcome the situation?

Answer (score 0):

The datatype length must be equal when using `UNPIVOT`. See this [**question**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/why-does-sql-server-require-the-datatype-length-to-be-the-same-when-using-unpivo) for more information. You should convert `U_ItemModality` to `VARCHAR(100)` so that it will have the same length as the other two columns.

```
select 
    cast(unpvt.ItemCode collate database_default AS VARCHAR(30)) as ItemCode,
    cast(unpvt.attribute collate database_default AS VARCHAR(30)) as attribute,
    cast(unpvt.value collate database_default AS VARCHAR(30)) as value 
from (
    select
        U_Mfg_Part_Num,
        U_Part_Descriptor,
        U_ItemModality = convert(varchar(100), U_ItemModality)
    from [OITM]
)t
unpivot (
    value for attribute in (U_Mfg_Part_Num, U_Part_Descriptor, U_ItemModality)
) unpvt
inner join [@AECTRANDATA] as WI 
    on unpvt.ItemCode = WI.U_ObjectKeyValue
inner join OITM AS IM 
    on WI.U_ObjectKeyValue = IM.ItemCode 
where 
    WI.U_ObjectType ='4'
```

Comment: I haven't tested the above query and I'm not also familiar with the `UNPIVOT` syntax. Proceed with caution.

Comment: Note that the CAST(... AS VARCHAR(30)) in the outer select will truncate your text if it is longer than 30 characters.

Comment: @mheptinstall, good catch. To avoid truncation, the length should be `100`.

Comment: The main query references `unpvt.ItemCode`. In order for the reference to work, the subselect should probably pull the `ItemCode` column from `[OITM]`.